# Setting System.Net.HttpWebRequest TransferEncoding to chunked always results in a exception

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, transfer-encoding

I'm trying to understand whether I'm missing something or whether it's a limitation in HttpWebRequest setting the TransferEncoding value to chunked.

The below code works perfectly fine, as long as I set the `SendChunked` to `true` before I set the TransferEncoding value

```
        var httpWebRequest1 = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://SomeApiHost.com/api/v1");
        httpWebRequest1.SendChunked = true;
        httpWebRequest1.TransferEncoding = "gzip";
```

however if I attempt the following:

```
        var httpWebRequest2 = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://SomeApiHost.com/api/v1");
        httpWebRequest2.SendChunked = true;
        httpWebRequest2.TransferEncoding = "Chunked";
```

I always get this exception

> Chunked encoding must be set via the SendChunked property. Parameter
> name: value

Using HttpClient works fine with the Chunked value, however I can't switch over to it as the RestSharp library uses HttpWebRequest

```
        var client1 = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient()
        client1.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked");
        client1.DefaultRequestHeaders.TransferEncodingChunked = true;
```

Does anyone know how to send the `Chunked` value in `TransferEncoding` with HttpWebReques?

Comment: If you target .NET Core, you're already using HttpClient. HttpWebRequest is just a legacy wrapper over HttpClient.

Comment: As for the error, it's pretty clear - don't use `TransferEncoding` to set chunked encoding, use `SendChunked`. Why are you using `TransferEncoding = "Chunked"` when you already used `.SendChunked = true;`? The HttpClient code you posted simply writes to the same header twice

Comment: Ah I see what I did there wrong, in order to get RestSharp to set the SendChunked to true you have to pass in a value for TransferEncoding, but testing now and passing in "" or null would actually allows it to be set without having to specify it being "chunked"
Thanks